# Sub-Martingale and Martingale

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

> An integrable sub-martingale $S_t$ with $\mathbb E(S_t)$ being a constant is a martingale.

Is this statement true, please? I think so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is.

You know that 
$$
E[S_{t+h}|S_t] \ge E[S_t]
$$

Th expectation of both terms if
$$
E[S_{t+h}] \ge E[S_t]
$$and as this is an euqality, you have a.s. equality in the first equation.

Comment: How do we have the second inequality, please?

Comment: this is the expectation of the first one.

Answer (score 3):

If $t>s$, then ${\rm E}[S_t\mid \mathcal{F}_s]-S_s\geq 0$ a.s. by the sub-martingale property. Since this random variable also has mean zero, we may conclude that it is zero a.s.